# Using Inheritance with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<UserTypes>
    <UserType Id="1">
        <Members>
            <Member UserTypeId="4" Name="Name1" />
            <Member UserTypeId="1" Name="Name2" />
        </Members>
    </UserType>
    <UserType Id="23" ItemUserTypeId="232">
        <Description />
    </UserType>
</UserTypes>
```

Some elements have specific nested elements and attributes. In `Java` I created general class and its heirs:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id", required = true)
    private Integer id;

    private UserTypeKind userTypeKindType;
    //getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StructUserType extends UserType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Members")
    MembersList membersList =  new MembersList();

    static class MembersList {
        @XmlElement(name = "Member")
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    static class Member {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
        String name;

        @XmlAttribute(name = "UserTypeId", required = true)
        long userTypeId;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListUserType extends UserType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ItemUserTypeId", required = true)
    private long itemUserTypeId;

    public long getItemUserTypeId() {
        return itemUserTypeId;
    }

    public void setItemUserTypeId(long itemUserTypeId) {
        this.itemUserTypeId = itemUserTypeId;
    }
}
```

I want marshall my objects to xml. I do:

```
List<UserType> userTypes = new ArrayList<>();

StructUserType structUserType = new StructUserType();
smbpStructUserType.setId(1);
SmbpStructUserType.Member member1  = new SmbpStructUserType.Member();
member1.name = "Name1";
member1.userTypeId = 4;
SmbpStructUserType.Member member2  = new SmbpStructUserType.Member();
member2.name = "Name2";
member2.userTypeId = 1;
structUserType.membersList.members.add(member1);
structUserType.membersList.members.add(member2);


ListUserType listUserType = new ListUserType();
listUserType.setId(23);
smbpListUserType.setItemUserTypeId(232);

userTypes.add(structUserType);
```

But when I try to do marshaling, only the elements that fall into the final xml are defined only in the main class (`UserType`), from which all are inherited. What is wrong with it? 
What kind of configuration of `JAXB` is needed so that the elements of the child classes also fall into the final xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few option I think. The easiest is give to your `UserType` tags two different name like `StructUserType` and `ListUserType`. Then you need to specify which name suitable for which class in root element

```
@XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "StructUserType", type = StructUserType.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "ListUserType", type = ListUserType.class)
    })
    private List<UserType> userTypse;
```

Another option is use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YourAddapter.class)`, extend XmlAdapter class in you YourAddapter class and override `marshal` method where you can specify how should be marshaled you UserType tag.

Comment: I used an annotation `@XmlSeeAlso({StructUserType.class,  ListUserType.class})` on my class. It worked. Is it correct?